# How can I get the volume enclosed by two orthogonal cylindrical surfaces (Radius is a variable, not a specific value)?

Tags: geometry

I can get the volume enclosed by two orthogonal cylindrical surfaces when the radius of the bottom circle of the cylinder is a specific value (for example, r1=r2=2):

```
    Clear["Global`*"];
    v1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 2^2, {x, y, z}];
    v2 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + z^2 <= 2^2, {x, y, z}];
    v = RegionIntersection[v1, v2];
    Volume[v]

(*128/3*)
```

How can I get the volume enclosed by two orthogonal cylindrical surfaces when the radius of the bottom circle of the cylinder is a variable "r" (r1==r2==r), not a specific value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
v1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, {x, y, z}];
v2 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + z^2 <= r^2, {x, y, z}];
v = RegionIntersection[v1, v2];
Assuming[r > 0, Volume[v]]
```

> `(16 r^3)/3`

Comment: Thanks!! @cvgmt

Comment: `Assuming[r > 0, ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, x^2 + z^2 <= r^2}, {x, y, z}] // Volume]`

Answer (score 4):

This was the fastest way that came to mind. Do a bunch of values and then guess the result. Like so:

```
Table[v1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, {x, y, z}];
 v2 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + z^2 <= r^2, {x, y, z}];
 v = RegionIntersection[v1, v2];
 Volume[v], {r, 1, 12, 1}]
```

> `{16/3, 128/3, 144, 1024/3, 2000/3, 1152, 5488/3, 8192/3, 3888, \ 16000/3, 21296/3, 9216}`

Then, you run

```
FindSequenceFunction[{16/3, 128/3, 144, 1024/3, 2000/3, 1152, 5488/3, 
  8192/3, 3888, 16000/3, 21296/3, 9216}, r]
```

which gives

> `(16 r^3)/3`

Bonus feature: rewrite it in terms of `π`.

```
Solve[16/3 xx == 4/3 Pi, xx] // Simplify
```

> `{{xx -> π/4}}`

Comment: Thanks :-) @kcr

Comment: @lotus2019 you are welcome :-)